# Find JSON nth value using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have this **JSON** values in **MySQL** database

Conditions

**1- >**

```
[{"offer_id":"158","offer_start":"2017-12-17 09:21:27","offer_ends":"2017-12-17 10:21:27"},{"offer_id":"167","offer_start":"2017-12-17 12:28:57","offer_ends":"2017-12-17 12:58:57"}]
```

**2 ->**

```
[{"offer_id":"170","offer_start":"2018-01-17 04:26:26","offer_ends":"2018-01-17 05:11:26"},{"offer_id":"167"}]
```

**3 ->**

```
[{"offer_id":"170","offer_start":"2017-12-11 20:49:12","offer_ends":"2017-12-11 20:49:12"}]
```

**3 ->**

```
[{"offer_id":"170"}]
```

So I need to get the nth **offer_ends** value **like "2017-12-11 20:49:12"** using mysql query

Comment: Is your json data stored in database table?

Comment: Yes which is stored like this field like offers -> [{"offer_id":"158","offer_start":"2018-02-20 10:44:06","offer_ends":"2018-02-20 11:44:06"},{"offer_id":"172","offer_start":"2018-02-20 14:01:25","offer_ends":"2018-02-20 15:01:25"},{"offer_id":"158","offer_start":"2018-02-20 15:21:55","offer_ends":"2018-02-20 16:21:55"}]

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you need to find the data from `table1` where the column name `offers`. You need to fetch data where the "offer_ends" has value `2017-12-11 20:49:12`

```
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(offers, '2017-12-11 20:49:12', '$.offer_ends')
FROM table1;
```

Get all the records:

```
SELECT offers, JSON_EXTRACT(offers, "$.offer_ends")
FROM table1
```

If you want then you can apply the order by on any column and then get the Top 1 record to get the last record.

Comment: Also Provide Reference For `JSON_CONTAINS`

Comment: We cant predict the nth value like this. So it may be any date based on the offer ends date. Here i need only the nth offer ends value

Comment: @BASILELDO you have an offer_id ?

Comment: @TarangP .Yes may be 158 or 170 and its dynamic

Comment: Means, you want the last record's offer end data?

Comment: @Mittal Can you check with this -> SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('[{"offer_id":"158","offer_start":"2018-02-20 10:44:06","offer_ends":"2018-02-20 11:44:06"},{"offer_id":"172","offer_start":"2018-02-20 14:01:25","offer_ends":"2018-02-20 15:01:25"},{"offer_id":"158","offer_start":"2018-02-20 15:21:55","offer_ends":"2018-02-20 16:21:55"}]', "$.offer_ends")

Comment: @Mittal Yes i need the nth record offer end data

Answer (score 0):

Here i have one code which get all the offer_ends value by using              MySQL  ->    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT('[{"offer_id":"23","offer_start":"2017-12-11 20:49:12","offer_ends":"2017-12-11 20:49:12"},{"offer_id":"23","offer_start":"2017-12-11 20:49:12","offer_ends":"2017-12-11 20:49:12"}]', '$[*].offer_ends'),'[',''),']','') as offer_dates

and the result is -> "2017-12-11 20:49:12", "2017-12-11 20:49:12" which shows all offer end dates

So i need to find the nth offer_ends value like this -> "2017-12-11 20:49:12"

Answer (score 0):

Guys  i found the solution

SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('[{"offer_id":"158","offer_start":"2018-02-21 13:03:15","offer_ends":"2018-02-21 14:03:15"},{"offer_id":"170","offer_start":"2018-02-21 15:03:15","offer_ends":"2018-02-21 16:03:15"}]',CONCAT("$[",JSON_LENGTH('[{"offer_id":"158","offer_start":"2018-02-21 13:03:15","offer_ends":"2018-02-21 14:03:15"},{"offer_id":"170","offer_start":"2018-02-21 15:03:15","offer_ends":"2018-02-21 16:03:15"}]')-1,"].offer_ends")) as offer

Thank you guys